# Is there a tool or library in iOS native development that manages/reads image/sprite sheets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, ios7

Image or Sprite sheet is pretty common in game development and I wanted to apply this mechanics to iOS native development so that most of the image assets is packaged in a single PNG file to minimize the app size.

Do you guys know an iOS native development tool or library for this?

Comment: The new Atlas feature in XCode 5 added with Sprite Kit might interest you. It makes sprites sheets for you, but I don't know if it can read one's you've already made.

Answer (score 0):

Its available in newer version of iOS i.e. iOS7, however if you use it you cannot give backward compatibility. Another good option that i have used as alternative of sprite is to use animated gif image and display in place of sprite animation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options for this, including the very popular [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) and the new [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043) framework in iOS 7.